# How can i set flag seen as mails in listview items using mailkit?

Tags: c#, listview, flags, items, mailkit

im begginer to c# and im trying to develop mail program. I don't know exactly what to do here.

I was add all mails to listview box like that ;

```
using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient())
            {
                client.Connect(server, port, true);
                client.Authenticate(mailBox.Text, passBox.Text);
                var inbox = client.Inbox;
                inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
                foreach (var items in list)
                    {
                            var mail = inbox.GetMessage(items.UniqueId);
                            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new[] {mail.Subject}
                            listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { item });
                    }
            }
```

I want to when i click listview item, selected mail will flagged as read.

(mailbox has 294 mails. When all mails added to listview box, i will click each item for mark as read)

Sorry my english is bad. I hope you understand...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to keep track of the UniqueId used to get the message, and then do this:

```
inbox.AddFlags (uid, MessageFlags.Seen, true);
```